# Does the Catholic Church have a written rule on the depth of a grave in a cemetery?

Tags: catholicism, tradition, burial

There is an old saying which goes like this : "A dead man is the landlord of six feet ! " It most probably owes its origin to the custom of burying the dead under six feet of land. I am curious to know if the Catholic Church has a written rule or protocol governing the depth of the grave in a cemetery that a grown-up dead faithful can be buried in.

Comment: Better to just specifically ask about the Catholic Church here I think.

Comment: There are rules for this for each cementary - also for cementaries governed by the Church. But I don't think there is a universal rule, but many local ones.

Comment: Most graves in the US are not 6 feet deep! See this article: [Why Are Graves Dug 6 Feet Deep?](https://www.verywellhealth.com/why-are-graves-dug-six-feet-deep-4047407)

Answer (score 4):

As far as universal rules are concerned, [Canon 1243](http://www.vatican.va/archive/ENG1104/__P4L.HTM) is relevant:

> 1243. Appropriate norms are to be enacted by particular law for the management of cemeteries, especially in what concerns the protection and fostering of their sacred character.

The depth of a grave is part of the cemetery's management, and is governed by “particular law” — which might be a civil law or a ruling in a particular territory (Conference or even diocese).

<sup>My translation is prepared by the Canon Law Society of Great Britain and Ireland, 1983</sup>